# Search page for Keyword and delete element that contains it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I'm writing a small jQuery script that I want to search a page for find all instances of a keyword then delete the elements in the DOM that contains the keyword.

I can't just do a find and replace as the keyword may only be one word but I want it to remove the whole paragraph that contains the keyword; or at least a sentence either side of it.

I figure jQuerys :contains seems to be a way to go for searching the page but that's about as far as I can figure out.

Comment: what have you done till now? please create a js fiddle for that

Comment: @Sandeeproop I don't have anything at the moment as I don't know where to start. Reading up on it seems to suggest using :contains but that's all I've got.

Comment: if there is same sequence in whole page like your content in p tag or div tag you can try each function on p or div to get html and then can find the element . if you able to find you can delete that element.